# AutoIt ControlSend does not send colon

Tags: autoit

I have an AutoIt script with a `ControlSend` statement:

```
ControlSend("[REGEXPTITLE:(Ordner ausw.*hlen);CLASS:#32770]", "", "Edit1", "C:\Dynamics", 1)
```

This worked for a while, but after several invocations of the script, suddenly the colon in **"C:\Dynamics"** was not sent any more. All I get is **"C\Dynamics"**, without the colon. This is very weird because it worked perfectly fine for a long time. I tried the same just with `Send`, but because the installation is behind a locked screen, `Send` does not recognize the opening window. I think ControlSend is the only way here.

Has anybody got an idea how I can get my colon back?

Comment: I tried it with a similar dialog and it worked as expected. AutoItSetOption('WinTitleMatchMode', 4)
AutoItSetOption('WinSearchChildren', 1)
ConsoleWrite(WinExists("[REGEXPTITLE:Speichern unter;CLASS:#32770]", ''))
ControlSend("[REGEXPTITLE:Speichern unter;CLASS:#32770]", "", "Edit1", "C:\Dynamics", 1) Which version of Autoit do you use?

Comment: Did you try to send the part before, the colon itself and the part after the colon separately with a `Sleep(1)` in between?

Comment: @Xenbiologist i use autoitv3 v3.3.10.2, this should be the latest version, i'll try to send it speparately and let you know if it works.

Comment: It works sometimes, but not everytime, this is really annoying

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread, but a lot of posts never resolve the issue.  Please do not delete the response.  You want to use the ControlSetText function if possible.  If that is not possible use a do until loop to check the text until its correct.

```cpp
Func getItRight($string)
    Do
        ControlSetText("Choose File to Upload", "", 1148, $string)
        $test = ControlGetText ("Choose File to Upload","", 1148)
    Until $string = $test
EndFunc
```

Comment: Your answer was probably deleted because it was more of a comment than an answer. (I realize you didn't have enough reputation to comment, back then.) But you're right about using `ControlGetText`, this is a good answer. I've written more here: A little late, but I experienced the same problem and finally found a solution. I've imported the alternate solution from the forums, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588904/controlsend-randomly-sending-wrong-characters-modified-and-unmodified