# ControlSend randomly sending wrong characters (modified and unmodified) when using SetKeyDelay, 0, 0

Tags: windows, autohotkey, modifier

I'm self-answering this question because I've seen it asked all over the Internet, but with few helpful answers, and definitely no resolutions on Stack Overflow that I can find.

#### Example Code

Consider this code, which simply writes several lines of shell commands:

```
^0::
    SetKeyDelay, 0, 0
    myWindow = ahk_exe Notepad.exe
    ControlSend, , set c=".cshrc-andrew.cheong"`n, %myWindow%
    ControlSend, , set v=".vimrc-andrew.cheong"`n, %myWindow%
    ControlSend, , foreach d ( /userhome/andrew.cheong /home/$USER /data/$USER )`n, %myWindow%
    ControlSend, , if ( -e $d/$c ) source $d/$c`n, %myWindow%
    ControlSend, , if ( -e $d/$v ) alias vim "vim -N -u $d/$v"`n, %myWindow%
    ControlSend, , end`n, %myWindow%
    Return
```

<sup>I'm writing the commands to Notepad to show that it is **not** an issue limited to terminal applications like PuTTy or xterm. It's easy to think so, since these applications sometimes have laggy behavior.</sup>

#### Example Output

Specifically when using `SetKeyDelay, 0, 0` for fast "typing," I get all kinds of weird behavior, like:

- Double-quotes replaced by single-quotes. Parentheses replaced by 9's and 0's. Dollar signs replaced by 4's.

  ```
  set c=".cshrc-andrew.cheong'
  set v=".vimrc-andrew.cheong"
  foreach d ( /userhome/andrew.cheong /home/$USER /data/$USER )
  if 9 -e 4d/4c 0 source 4d/4c
  if ( -e $d/$v ) alias vim 'vim -n -u 4d/4v'
  end
  ```
- Dashes replaced by underscores. Case changes.

  ```
  set c='.cshrc-andrew.cheong"
  set v='.vimrc-andrew.cheong'
  foreach d ( /userhome/andrew.cheong /home/4user /data/$USER )
  if 9 -e 4d/$C ) source 4d/$c
  if 9 _e $d/$v ) alias vim 'vim -N -u $d/$v"
  end
  ```
- Periods replaced by >'s. More case changes.

  ```
  set c=".cshrc-andrew.cheong"
  set v=">VIMrc-andrew.cheong"
  foreach d ( /userhome/andrew.cheong /home/$USER /data/$USER )
  if 9 -e $d/$c ) source 4d/$c
  if ( -e $d/$V ) alias vim "vim -N -u $d/$v"
  end
  ```

It's obvious the issue has something to do with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier, as if it's being randomly turned on or off.

**Why is this happening, and how do we fix it?**

Note that there are no problems when using `Send` and its variants. The issue specifically arises with `ControlSend`, which is needed to send inputs to specific controls or to an unfocused window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

Copy this into your script (from user RHCP at AutoHotkey forums):

```
pSendChars(string, control := "", WinTitle := "", WinText := "", ExcludeTitle := "", ExcludeText := "")
{
    for k, char in StrSplit(string)
        postmessage, WM_CHAR := 0x102, Asc(char),, %Control%, %WinTitle%, %WinText%, %ExcludeTitle%, %ExcludeText%
    return
}
```

And use it like this:

```
^0::
    myWindow = ahk_exe Notepad.exe
    line .= "set c="".cshrc-acheong""`n"
    line .= "set v="".vimrc-acheong""`n"
    line .= "foreach d ( /userhome/andrew.cheong /home/cama /home/$USER )`n"
    line .= "    if ( -e $d/$c ) source $d/$c`n"
    line .= "    if ( -e $d/$v ) alias vim ""vim -N -u $d/$v""`n"
    line .= "end`n"
    pSendChars(line, "edit1", myWindow)
    Return
```

That's it.

<sup>Note that `edit1` is Notepad's name for its text control. When using this script for PuTTy, I changed it to a blank string. Use AutoHotkey's WindowSpy program to find out the control you wish to write to.</sup>

#### Why

> This has come up a few times before. Just to add to what Lexikos
>   wrote, the issue is due to the fact that controlSend uses both post
>   message and sendInput/sendEvent to send keystrokes. This is required
>   as some programs will not correctly interpret the keystrokes unless
>   the sent modifier keys are logically down (sent via sendInput/Event).
>
> Modifier keys (unless explicitly stated e.g. {shitft down}) are sent
>   via sendInput while non-modifers are sent via postMessage. Keys sent
>   via postmessage are sent directly to the window and so have less delay
>   than the other keys/messages. Consequently it's possible for keystroke
>   messages to arrive out of synch resulting in unexpected characters. In
>   your case the capitalised letters require the shift key to be sent via
>   sendInput/Event.
>
> In addition to using keyDelays, you can try controlSetText and posting
>   WM_Char messages.  If you're working with a text control i would
>   recommend using controlSetText.
>
> - [RHCP on 30 Sep 2013](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=38107#p38107)

Comment: The function works very well. Speed and more importantly reliability increased substantially. I had to upgrade from an older version of AHK to get it to work on one computer. I didn't check the old version before upgrading but it was one with the smaller Spy Window. Thanks for the tip. More tips like this would be appreciated.